# I am having trouble assigning an Array?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble with this piece of code and I can't figure out how to get it to work. I can't figure out what the problem is as to me it looks like it should work. The string array called m_nameList on both places are marked as 'An object reference required for the non static feild, method, or property 'Solutionname.classname.m_nameList'

the code:

```
    public static bool CheckVacantSeats(int seatNumber)
    {            
        if (m_nameList[seatNumber] == null)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

m_nameList is an array that is declared in an constructor before this static bool:

```
     public SeatManager(int maxNumberOfSeats)
    {
        m_totNumOfSeats = maxNumberOfSeats;
        m_nameList = new string[m_totNumOfSeats];
        m_priceList = new double[m_totNumOfSeats];
    }
```

I am calling the CheckVacantSeat from another class with this:

```
  bool validSeats = SeatManager.CheckVacantSeats(seatNumber, m_nameList);
```

I can't figure out what is wrong with it. So i need some help figuring out why m_nameList does not work for me?

Thanks in advance!!

//Regards

Comment: Standard error: rewrite `if (x)  return true; else return false;` to `return x;` – **always**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have marked your method as static. Since it is static, it has "no" state, and cannot access class members which are not marked as static.

You can mark m_nameList as static, but that means that it's value is shared across all reads and writes. m_nameList looks like a simple lookup table so maybe this is what you want?

Recommended reading is [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) and [Static Classes and Static Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Exactly, how would it know which instance of a member to access?

Comment: (help you with a better word) Reads and Writes?

Answer (score 1):

Your function is static, but your variables are not static.

Answer (score 1):

Well your call is wrong for a start, your method `CheckVacantSeats` only accepts one parameter so you can't call it with two??!

```
CheckVacantSeats(int seatNumber)
SeatManager.CheckVacantSeats(seatNumber, m_nameList);
```

your method is also static so there's no point having a constructor.

I think what your after is:

```
SeatManager seatManager = new SeatManager(maxNumberOfSeats);
seatManager.CheckVacantSeats(seatNumber);
```

**Also**

```
public bool CheckVacantSeats(int seatNumber)
    {            
        if (m_nameList[seatNumber] == null)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing two concepts: an instance initialized with a constructor, and a static class with static members. You cannot expect a static member method to access a non-static field. I guess your `m_nameList` field is static as well, otherwise your code wouldn't even compile. You should choose either way:

1. make all `SeatManager`'s members non-static;
2. turn the `SeatManager` class into a static class having all members static.

Since you need to initialize the `SeatManager` with the total number of seats, the better way seems to be No. (1). Then instead of `SeatManager.CheckVacantSeats()` you would call an instance like `mySeatManager.CheckVacantSeats()`. Even in case there will always be just one instance of `SeatManager` — a singleton — this approach is better. With a singleton, you could end up with a `public static SeatManager Instance { get; set; }` property in `SeatManager` and work with it like this: `SeatManager.Instace.CheckVacantSeats()`. This is usually called a [*singleton pattern*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).